# What is the proper syntax for using variables inside of "url(' ')" when trying to change the background of an image? Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, url, syntax

I'm trying to consistently cycle what my background image is using an Array variable, but I cannot seem to figure out how to properly write the variable into the url section.

```
window.setInterval (function borderChange() {
    var backgrounds = [
        "../pictures/background1.png",
        "../pictures/background2.png",
        "../pictures/background3.png",
        "../pictures/background4.png"
    ];
    var counter = 0;
    document.getElementById("borderOne").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+backgrounds[counter]+"')";
    counter++;
    if (counter == 4) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}, 5000)
```

I've tried writing the url line in the following ways (and many more that gave me errors in VS) with no luck:

```
"url('"+backgrounds[counter]+"')";
"url('" + backgrounds[counter] + "')";
"url('' + "+backgrounds[counter]+")";
"url(";backgrounds[counter];")";
"url("+backgrounds[counter]+")";
```

Comment: I'm not sure your JavaScript itself is valid - try moving your `function borderChange() { .. }` to a higher scope and having `window.setInterval( borderChange, 5000 );` without parenthesis after `borderChange`).

Comment: Additionally, your `counter` value will always be zero every time your `borderChange` function runs because your `var counter = 0` will re-set it on every invocation.

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening. You can use some dummy images for `backgrounds` array.

Comment: Both suggestions worked, but moving the variables out of the function seemed to be the easiest fix. Thanks you @Dai!

Comment: @palaѕн I'm actually extremely new and don't have experience with jsfiddle or snippet yet so I would not be able to do that. I have it figured out now though, thanks for your interest in helping.

Comment: No problem. Glad that your issue was resolved finally.